# Get the whole table and set to editor's content

Tags: asp.net, html-table, telerik, radeditor

I have a table and Rad Editor likes

```
  <table id="MyTable" width="200" border="1" cellpadding="8" style="display:none">
  <tr>
  <td><p id="Title" runat="server" style="text-align: center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><p id="Description" runat="server" style="text-align: center"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

    <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" Enabled="false"  
    ContentFilters="DefaultFilters,PdfExportFilter">
    <ExportSettings OpenInNewWindow="true" />
    </telerik:RadEditor>
```

I set the values of `Title` and `Description` dynamically .
What I want to do is , after setting the inner text of the table , want to show this table in `RadEditor1`'s content !
I can add table in editor's content likes

```
    <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" Enabled="false"  
    ContentFilters="DefaultFilters,PdfExportFilter">
    <ExportSettings OpenInNewWindow="true" />
    <content>
    <table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="8" style="display:none">
     ........
    </table>
    </content>
    </telerik:RadEditor>
```

But using this way , I can't access `Title` and `Description` by ID .
And I've tried likes this

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    MyTable.RenderControl(hw);
    RadEditor1.Content = sb.ToString();
```

But it's doesn't work for me , `sb.ToString()` always return empty string !
How can i get the whole table and set this to editor's content ? Can I use jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can built the table on the server with the content you desire, make it a method that will return the table and will receive two string arguments for the title and description. The string this method will return can be set to the RadEditor1.Content property.

Another option is the [client-side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html) of the control - the [set_html(html)](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-set-html.html) and [pasteHtml(html)](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-pastehtml.html) methods.